# I can't understand the overflow-x and overflow-y property of this following example

Tags: css, overflow

If I use overflow-y = scroll; property, the texts are scrolled vertically as usual. But again If I use overflow-x = scroll; property, I see in the browser that the box shows the left and right arrow. Well, but I can't scroll left or right dimension or more specifically to say horizontally. The text still scrolled vertically. Why the text isn't scrolled horizontally in this case???

```
/* Here is the example of overflow property */
.box {
    height: 100px;
    width: 200px;
    border: 4px solid green;
    overflow-x: scroll;
}

.box {
    height: 100px;
    width: 200px;
    border: 4px solid green;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

[image: the 1st pic is when I use overflow-x: scroll; property]

[image: the 2nd pic is when I use overflow-y: scroll; property]

Comment: because there is nothing to scroll, all the content is already visible

Comment: I think inside `box` element there should be another wrapper that will hold the texts. The width of that inside element will be larger than `box` then you can scroll horizontally. But without any html code I am just guessing. You should add some html code you are trying.

Comment: `scroll` forces scrollbars to appear, this is useful to let users know that a certain container may contain more content than visible and expect a scrollbar, the behavior you're looking for is `auto` which only adds scrollbars if needed

Comment: its better to use `overflow-x: auto`. it adds an scrollbar if the content is too big

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow-x),

> The overflow-x CSS property sets what **shows when content overflows a block-level element's left and right edges**. This may be nothing, a scroll bar, or the overflow content.

In your example, the content is **NOT** overflowing the edges and simple wrapping to the next line. This is because you probably have simple text in your container and the normal value for `word-wrap` property for text is `normal` (which "Break words only at allowed break points"). So the text just wraps.

If, for example, you had a `div` inside that was exceeding the width of this container - then your `overflow` property would kick in. Alternatively, if your text inside was a single continuous string with no spaces (hence not allowed to wrap with `normal`) with a width greater than the width the parent, the scrollbar would be visible.

I added some examples below to demonstrate this:

```css
.box {
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 200px;
  width: 100px;
  margin: 10px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  display: inline-block;
}

.long-box {
 width: 300px;
}

.scroll-x {
  overflow-x: scroll;
}

.word-wrap {
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<!-- 
    Doesnot scroll, 
    width adheres to left/right edges 
-->
<div class='box scroll-x'>
  <b>Will not scroll</b>
  Scroll X with content less than width
</div>

<!-- 
     Will not scroll, 
     because of the really long word,
     and since `word-wrap` by default is `normal` so the content overflows 
-->
<div class='box scroll-x'>
  <b>Will scroll</b>
    Scroll X with content greater than width 
  LoremipsumLoreLoremipsumLoremLoremipsumLoremLoremipsumLorem
</div>

<!--
     Will not scroll 
     because this now has `word-wrap` set to `break-word`-->
<div class='box scroll-x word-wrap'>
  <b>Will not scroll</b>
  Scroll X with content greater than width but with word wrap
  LoremipsumLoreLoremipsumLoremLoremipsumLoremLoremipsumLorem
</div>

<!-- 
     Will scroll, 
     because of the div inside,
     that is 300px, i.e > width of box (200px) 
-->
<div class='box scroll-x'>
  <b>Will scroll</b>
  Scroll X with content (long-box) greater width 
  <div class='long-box'>...</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```css
.yourclass {
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.yourclass {
  overflow-x: auto;
}
```